# Как в Spring WebFlux использовать Gson вместо Jackson?

Tags: java, spring, gson

Не думал что придется тратить на это время,но уже изрядно потрепался в поисках ответа.Использование **spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson** как в дефолтном Spring Boot не работает.Заранее спасибо,ибо на англоязычных источниках,да и в наших,информации нету или крайне мало.Возможно я упустил что-то?